# How to add linter after initializing had done using vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

i didn't enable lint when i first initialized webpack-template using vue-cli. But now i want to lint. How can i formally add lint feature on my current vuejs project using vue-cli without manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm install eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-html eslint-config-standard
```

Then create a file called `.eslintrc.js` and make it look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  extends: 'standard',
  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'html'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  'rules': {

    // allow paren-less arrow functions
    'arrow-parens': 0,
    // allow async-await
    'generator-star-spacing': 0,
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the new way to do this is to add it with vue-add:

`vue add eslint`

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#plugins